# How many triangles in a chess board, allowing diagonals?

Tags: triangles, puzzle, chessboard

So I saw a question about how many rectangles in a grid of squares that looked like an "L", and it got me thinking: If we have an $8\times 8$ grid, how many triangles are there? This has its own issue of what angles the triangles have, so to be precise:

> How many triangles are there in $8\times 8$ grid when you can only create diagonals?
>
> Rules: A triangle can only be created by square diagonals (the building block square $1\times 1$). Meaning, the triangle sides do not cross the squires side (aka it has to cut through the corners only). Lastly, a triangle side **can** cut another triangle side. (So basically each individual square have 8 triangles.)

You can check the figure for example triangles which are possible:

[image]

Comment: After a little bit of thought (while in bed trying to sleep) do i just count the number of rectangles and just multiply it by 8?

Comment: To be clear, you mean only right isosceles triangles right? For example the triangle formed by the L-shape a knight can move in is not to be counted?

Comment: as long as the triangle sides do not cross the squires side (aka it has to cut through the corners only)

Comment: It seems to me we need to enumerate all squares and rectangles with form factor $2:1$, since these are the only shapes that can embed such triangles.

Comment: zwim you are right if the rectangle ratio is not 2 : 1 it will not work.

Comment: @FeerasAldoheiman then that would be a yes: if you only cross at corners, then each vertex of the triangle either bisects the corner (45 degrees) or follows it (90 degrees), which forms 45-45-90 right triangles. I have an idea for an argument using symmetry, I'll try to answer.

Comment: @ccroth I have edited the Question and added the rules of creating the triangles just to have a clear question

Comment: @FeerasAldoheiman according to your edit each square has 8 triangles. Can you draw out these 8 triangles? Visualizing it, these triangles will have sides with less than unit length (length 1). Are you sure you would like to allow this?

Comment: @ccroth Sure check picture.to explain, if you draw both diagonals that will result in 4 triangles but each 2 that share the same diagonal make a bigger triangle. (in the picture triangles 5+6 makes up triangle 1, 7+8 makes 2, 5+8 makes 3, and lastly 7 + 6 makes 4)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main types of triangle. Those with one horizontal/vertical side and two diagonals, and those with two horizontal/vertical sides and one diagonals.

**Case 1: One horizontal/vertical side.**
Let's assume for now that it has a horizontal base, with the diagonal sides going up. Depending on the length of the base we have:
Base length $1$: $8\times8$
Base length $2$: $8\times7$
Base length $3$: $7\times6$
...
Base length $n$: $(9-\lceil n/2\rceil)\times(9-n)$
The first factor is the possibilities for the y coordinate, the second factor the number of possibilities for the x coordinate.

This adds to $64+56+42+35+24+18+10+5=254$. This has to be multiplied by 4 to get all 4 orientations, so there are $4\times254=1016$ triangles of this type.

**Case 2: One diagonal side.**
Let's assume for now that the right angle is at the bottom-left. Depending on the length of the legs at that corner we have:
Base length $1$: $8\times8$
Base length $2$: $7\times7$
Base length $3$: $6\times6$
...
Base length $n$: $(9-n)\times(9-n)$

This adds to $64+49+36+25+16+9+4+1=204$. Again this has to be multiplied by 4 to get all 4 orientations, so there are $4\times204=816$ triangles of this type.

Adding these two cases together gives a grand total of $1016+816=1832$ triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Number of squares : $$S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2=204$$

- $8\times 8$ squares of side $1$
- $7\times 7$ squares of side $2$
- $\cdots$
- $1\times 1$ square of side $8$

Number of form factor $2:1$ horizontal rectangles : $$R_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}(n+1-i)(n+1-2i)=114$$

- $8\times 7$ rectangles of sides $2\times 1$
- $7\times 5$ rectangles of sides $4\times 2$
- $6\times 3$ rectangles of sides $6\times 3$
- $5\times 1$ rectangles of sides $8\times 4$

There are $4$ triangles by square, and $2$ triangles per rectangle and we have also vertical rectangles, this is giving:

$$T_n=4(S_n+R_n)=1272\text{ triangles}$$

Comment: You are missing triangles with an odd-length base, e.g. the two in a rectangle of size $7\times4$  where the triangles have their apex at the centre of a unit square rather than on the edge of that rectangle.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis This was deliberate on my part: I excluded points not in the grid. If we want to consider unit square centers, why not taking a finer grid ?

Comment: It also means that you are not including the triangles marked 5,6,7,8 in the picture in the question, even though they should (see comments under the question).